# MSPointer equivalent for "touchend"

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, touch, internet-explorer-10

I am porting a piece of code for an HTML5 app from iOS/Android to Windows Phone 8. In this App there is a vertical scroll view with a number of elements. 
In the original App I use "touchstart" and "touchend" events. This means every time the user touches the List I get a touchstart event, and even after scrolling around, when the user lifts the finger I get a touchend.

The MSPointer model works different. There is MSPointerDown which is the exact equivalent of touchstart, so no problem on this end.
I can't get my head around how to model the touchend behaviour though. MSPointerUp is not enough because it is only thrown if the user lifts its finger inside the same container where the MSPointerDown occurred. So if a user touches the list, then swipes it up and then lifts the finger, the event will not be fired. There is also MSPointerOut, which triggers when a user leaves the container where MSPointerUp was fired, the problem here is, it fires as soon as the container is left (so during the scrolling of the list) and doesn't fire after the user lifts its finger.

I'm a bit on a loss here how to model a "touchend" with MSPointer that will trigger in exact the same way as the Webkit one.

Cheers

Tom

Comment: Have you looked into pointercancel? It seems like it could work for you...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh846776(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The problem with pointercancel is that it is fired after the user swipes a certain fixed distance (even if he doesn't lift the finger). Cancel indicates that the event beginning with pointerdown will not fire a pointerup (for various reasons, either because the user left the pointerdown area or the swipe was too long)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I handle this issue.

Even though the Down/Move listeners are attached to some element, I attach the Up listener to the window.
This means that no matter where on the screen the user lifts the finger/pen/mouse (even outside the browser window in IE on a PC), the Up event is triggered.
This also means that you must handle all Up events in your app in one function.  But you can set a flag (some global variable) on an element's Down event, and check for that flag in the UP event.

I've been doing this for a long time for mouse events on PC web pages, to handle when the user let's go of the mouse button outside the browser window.
It's annoying when they don't do this, like in Google Maps Street View where you're trying to pan around far and have to move the mouse a lot, and you let go of the button outside the window but it still thinks you're dragging.